# Mobile Responsiveness

Tags: responsive-design

I am beginning a landing page for a client. I have made it responsive, but when I open it up on a mobile phone, it pops up large and cuts off the page. I have to pinch the screen and zoom out in order to get the full content. How can I code it to where it is already just 100% there without having to zoom out?

Comment: Please share your code or media query at least

Answer (score 0):

Whether use CSS [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) or Boostrap framework which will provide you with predefined classes to add to your HTML elements in order for them to adapt on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you haven't hard-coded widths for any images, divs or other elements on the page. Instead use relative sizes when you can, eg `width: 50vw;` . Setting max-widths is sometimes necessary as well, eg `max-width:100%;`

As per the earlier suggestion from Blueware, media queries will help you set styles based on the viewport or window size.

Also check that you have included a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) in the head of your page:

```
<head>  
....  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...
</head>
```

If still no joy, post some code or a URL.

Good luck!